# GroupBy of huge spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate

I have a dataframe with thousands of millions of rows with columns 'A', 'B' and others. The df is saved in parquet format partitioned by 'A'. If I run:

```
df.groupBy('A').agg(agg_functions)
```

It works, but if I run:

```
df.groupBy('B').agg(agg_functions)
```

The process fails because of lack of memory (it tries to bring all data to a executor). 
I know there is a relation between A, B: the same value for B can only appear in two consecutive partitions of A. Is there any way to use this fact to perform the operation efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to group by two columns and aggregate twice. For example, If i had three columns (country, city and orders), assume in this case your column 'A' is country and City is 'B'. Now if i want to get all the orders grouped by country, I could do,

```
df.groupBy("country").agg(count)
```

Some partitions can be huge like your case, so i could rather do something like,

```
intermediateResults = df.groupBy("country","city").agg(count)
intermediateResults.groupBy("country").agg(sum)
```

You might not always have this relation between columns, in which case you could split it up across time or id's.

Comment: I like the idea!! But it isn't still suitable in my case, because some of the aggregation methods are F.countDistinct() functions, that could not aggregated in two steps.